# Python Opencv img.item() performance too slow

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

i wrote this little code to compare the pixels greyscale values of two 100x100 jpeg images.
However, the performance is very disappointing (1.5 Seconds for 10.000 comparisons). Is there a way to achieve a better performance?

Here is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math
import datetime


img1 = cv2.imread('Testbild 2014-08-23 17:27:25.141362.jpeg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img2 = cv2.imread('Testbild 2014-08-23 17:27:25.061802.jpeg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

height, width =img1.shape
cnt = 0
threshold = 10

print("start:" + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
for y in range(0 , height):
    for x in range(0 , width):
        val1 = img1.item(y,x)
        val2 = img2.item(y,x)
        diff_abs = math.fabs(int(val1)-int(val2))
        if diff_abs > threshold:
            cnt += 1      
        if x == height and y == width:
            break
        if x == height:
            x=0
        if y == width:
            y=0     

print("end:" + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
print("Result: " + str(cnt))
```

Many thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The double loop:

```
for y in range(0 , height):
    for x in range(0 , width):
        val1 = img1.item(y,x)
        val2 = img2.item(y,x)
        diff_abs = math.fabs(int(val1)-int(val2))
        if diff_abs > threshold:
            cnt += 1      
        if x == height and y == width:
            break
        if x == height:
            x=0
        if y == width:
            y=0
```

can be replaced by:

```
diff_abs = np.abs(img1-img2)
cnt = (diff_abs > threshold).sum()
```

This takes advantage of NumPy array's ability to do [fast element-wise arithmetic](https://web.archive.org/web/20150802020005/http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial#head-4c1d53fe504adc97baf27b65513b4b97586a4fc5).

---

The condition

```
 x == height and y == width
```

is never true. If `height < width`, then `y` will never equal `width` (since `y` is in `range(0, height)`). If `height > width`, then `x` will never equal `height`. and if `height == width`, then neither `x` nor `y` will ever equal `height`.

---

The condition

```
    if x == height:
        x=0
```

does nothing useful, since even if `x == height`, the assignment to `x` is lost on the next iteration of the loop.

The same goes for

```
    if y == width:
        y=0
```

Comment: You are the man! Execution time down to 0.01 second - exceeded my expectations. Many thanks. Sorry about the confusion with x and y and thanks for the additional explanation.